# Cannot reproduce SOAP requests sent by an .exe file in Postman or SoupUI

Tags: http, soap, postman

I tried to reproduce a bunch of SOAP requests sent by an .exe file in Postman but the API end point does not send back the correct result.

I constructed a request exactly like the one captured with Wireshark, but the response is not correct.

What seems to be the problem? What am I missing?

**Update:** 
I just tried to send these request using `SoapUI` instead of `Postman` and with `SoapUI` the response is a SOAP response so it seems more correct, the endpoint still doesn't send back correct result, but at least the response is a SOAP response now. 
Apparently Postman messes up the SOAP request in some way.

Comment: Anybody? I just wonder how come two identical requests have different results, I guess the Web Server does some sort of sniffing to detect the source of the request.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Solution:**

1. I created a soap service with `SoapUI` and used the `wsdl.xml` file provided by the web service
2. `SoapUI` automatically generated all operations/requests defined in the `wsdl.xml`
3. I sent these auto generated requests made by `SoapUI` and they worked.
4. So I compared these requests with the ones I was sending and realized the syntax (`xml` body of the request) of these auto generated requests was different than the ones described in the web service doc.

but there are still some weird things that I don't understand, like the requests I captured with `Wireshark` had the same `xml` body as in the Doc described but they were successful responses.